# facing issue while using feeding actionbar library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to import [This](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) project and its not proprly import giving me redline( project name is actionbarcompat).

```
private ActionBar getActionBar(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof ActionBarActivity) {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar();
    }
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBarWithReflection(activity, "getSupportActionBar");
    if (actionBar == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Activity should derive from ActionBarActivity "
            + "or implement a method called getSupportActionBar");
    }
    return actionBar;
}
```

based on this line `Activity should derive from ActionBarActivity "
                + "or implement a method called getSupportActionBar`

i assume i am not able to detect actionbar.

Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: What does your Activity extend ?

Comment: public final class FadingActionBarHelper extends FadingActionBarHelperBase {

i have added library project and i m able to detect FadingActionBarHelperBase

Comment: What is  `FadingActionBarHelperBase` Is it a BaseActivity?

Comment: There two project actionbarcompat,actionbarsherlock in both project i am getting same problem.
@ Raghunandan can you please try to import in your eclipse and give me solution for that.

Comment: if you appcompat there i no need for actionbarsherlock

Comment: soo i dont need actionbarsherlock.
have you import the project..??did you got error or you can successfully compile the project.